# Updating a default Phone Number

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an `EditText` field, which I have a default value from 

`strings.xml ( android:text="@string/DefaultMobileNumber")`.
When the user updates this (button listener), I am storing the new value in **`SHARED_PREFERENCES`**, however, the new value will not show on screen when the page is re-displayed (the default from strings.xml persisits). I am using

```
final EditText phoneNoText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.InPhone);
    if (mSettings.contains(PREFERENCES_PHONENO)) {
        String sPhoneNoText = (mSettings.getString(PREFERENCES_PHONENO,"No Number"));
        phoneNoText.setText(sPhoneNoText);
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sPhoneNoText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {// write default value to PREFERENCES_PHONENO
        editor.putString(PREFERENCES_PHONENO, "07799060000");
        editor.commit();
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    };
```

Hopefully I've made a stupid error, but can't seem to find it!!!

Comment: What's `@string/DefaultMobileNumber` set to?

Comment: the above code will not save phone no. second time. Change your if conditions.

Comment: Thanks for thoughts, much appreciated.
I had the initialisation code in a subroutine. I have re-jigged the and got it working.
More testing me thinks!!!